# I want to print my Blog Posts

Tags: html, css, printing

I have build a little Blog and want to print my Posts. I know that I must do this with `CSS` and I have tried some `Stylesheets` to do this.

But my problem is,

1) Each post should get a A4 page out of the contribution, if it is too long then it should get two or more pages.

How can I solve this problem only with `CSS` ?

Here my first tries.

```
@media print {
[class*="col-sm-"] {
    float: left;
}
ul,a,.btn,h1,.pager,.text-muted {
    display: none;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background: none;
}
.col-md-8 {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm assuming you are printing multiple posts from a single page in the browser. Yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) or [`page-break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) properties.

Without seeing your HTML I can't give you the exact answer, but here's what you need to accomplish:

1. Find an element in your HTML that contains each post. (This might be
   something like `<div class="post">` or `<article>`, etc.)
2. Add a block to your CSS inside `@media print {` for those elements along the lines of

```css
.post {
   page-break-after: always;
}
```